# jQuery add class, wait, then change that class?

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class when an element is clicked (eg transitioning), then wait for 1 second and change that class (eg finished-transitioning).

I've tried this:

```
$(this).addClass('transition').delay(1000).addClass('active');
```

UPDATE - Why does the following not work? When I uncomment the alert I can see it fires at the correct time however `addClass` and `removeClass` are ignored.

```
$('.target').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('transition'); 

    $('.target').not(this).removeClass('active transition');

    setTimeout(function(){  
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //  alert('test');
    },300);

});
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: 2100 SO rep and no code? Dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout(), like this:

```
$('.target').click(function () {
    var $target = $(this);

    $target.addClass('transition');

    $('.target').not(this).removeClass('active transition');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $target.removeClass('transition').addClass('active');
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/2jq85/)

I think the issue with your code is that you are trying to use `$(this)` inside the function you pass to setTimeout(), but within that function `this` does not refer to the element. The code above avoids that by defining the `$target` variable.

Another way to fix your code would be to use the `$.proxy()` function to set the context for the callback function, like this:

```
$('.target').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('transition');

    $('.target').not(this).removeClass('active transition');

    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('transition').addClass('active');
    }, this), 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('p').css('color', 'red').delay(1000).queue(

function (aaa)
{
   $(this).css('color', 'green');
   $(this).dequeue(); //<---- or  aaa();  , will work also
}).Continue...
```

Example : http://jsbin.com/ocOkIfA/2/edit

Look here at jquery :

[image]

By default the queue for which you can add delay is only for FX.

setting css prop is not an animation  - hence it is not using the queue.

so that's what we did.

Comment: You might want to explain that `addClass` doesn't directly mix with the animation queue (and thus `delay`).